# How do I prove/disprove the following linear transformation statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to prove\disprove that if $V$ is vector space and $T: V \rightarrow V$ is linear transformation such that $T^2 = 0$, then $Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: If $y=Tx$, then $Ty=$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}x\in\im T$. 
Then there exists an $y\in V$ such that $T(y) = x$. 
(If this $y$ would not exist, then $x$ would not be element of the image set of $T$)

Then $T(x) = T(T(y)) = T^2(y) = 0$, by definition of $T^2$, thus $x\in\ker T$.

This means $\im T \subseteq \ker T$.